# Weblogic14 throws target state: deploy failed Servlet class: com.org.TestServlet1.com does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws, java-11

Im trying to update an existing JAX-WS app creation scenario to work with Java11.

Existing code:

```
    // import javax.jws.WebService;
    // import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    // import javax.jws.WebParam;
    // import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;
    // import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
   
    import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
    import jakarta.jws.WebParam;
    import jakarta.jws.WebService;
    import jakarta.xml.ws.BindingType;
    import jakarta.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;
    
   /*
     security imports
   */

    
    @WebService(portName = "TestPort")
    @BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
    public class TestServlet1 {
        @WebMethod
        public String echo(@WebParam(name = "arg0") String str) {
         // Some Code
  }
}
```

Now here is how the process goes, The above JaxwsService is first compiled, then wsdl files are generated from them using the ant wsgen task and lastly bundled for deployment.

The issue arises when i try to deploy the .was file using Weblogic deployer, The deployment fails with the following error message:

```
Task 83 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application JaxwsService on MServerB.
Target state: deploy failed on Server MServerB
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet class: 'org.example.JaxwsService' does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet
```

Now if i switch back the imports to javax.jws.* the javaCompilation and ant.wsgen generation fails because they both dont work with javax.jws.* imports.

Any leads would help.